# FileUpload Control in Mono

Tags: asp.net, .net, apache, file-upload, mono

I have encoutered a question when I run ASP.NET on Mono+Apache2.
I put a FileUpload Control in a Page,when click button to upload the file it will throw an Exception:

> Could not find a part of the path "/var/www/www.mysite.com/upload/headImage/uid_1.jpg".
>
> Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/var/www/www.mysite.com/upload/headImage/uid_1.jpg".
> at System.IO.File.Delete (System.String path) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs (System.String filename) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload.SaveAs (System.String filename) [0x00000] in >:0
> at WebApplication.users.ImageUpload.btnUpload_Click (System.Object sender, >System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent (System.String eventArgument) >[0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent >(System.String eventArgument) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent (IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, >System.String eventArgument) [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvents () [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRaiseEvents () [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.Page.InternalProcessRequest () [0x00000] in :0
> at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in :0

I'm sure the path "/var/www/www.mysite.com/upload/headImage/" exist and have been chmod 766 and there isn't exists "uid_1.jpg" in that folder.

Source code:

```
string fileName = "uid_1.jpg";
string imageUrl = "/upload/headImage/" + fileName;
fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/upload/headImage/"), fileName);
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
   File.Delete(fileName);
}

upload.SaveAs(fileName);
```

Could anyone can tell how to do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!
When I use chmod 777 /var/www/www.mysite.com/upload/headImage/,I found I can upload files to server now.

Comment: But I think maybe it was the best way,anyone else can tell me a better solution?